# svn revert from changeset

Tags: svn

Is there a way to revert from a particular changeset?

The changes has been committed, as I see from the changeset. Now, I want to revert back the files from before they were committed.

I did svn revert path/to/file but it's not asking for a password or anything. Nothing is happening.

Comment: nothing is happening when I do svn revert per file.

Comment: Please be even more elaborate. If the changes have been committed, you can revert to a revision pre commit ...

Comment: svn revert — Undo all local edits. As the documentation says, it does not revert committed revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: 
svn merge -r1234:4321 path/to/yourfile path/to/thefileyouwanttogobackto,

where 
1234 is your revision 
4321 is the revision you want to go back to.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a "reverse merge" i.e. "apply" all the changes FROM your current revision TO the revision you want to go back to (i.e. undo all the changes FROM the revision you want to go back to TO the current revision).

```
svn merge -r HEAD:nnnn .
```

where `nnnn` is the revision you want to go back to. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html

After reviewing the changes, resolving any conflicts etc., use `svn commit` to push the changes to the repository.

Comment: Yes thank you zellus, my mistake! I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo talks in detail about reverting commits.

Comment: It said "cannot replace a directory from within"

Comment: Solved: svn merge -r1234:4321 path/to/yourfile path/to/theirfile, where 1234 is your revision and 4321 is the revision you want to go back to.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is described in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo):

```
$ svn merge -c -303 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

That will undo any changes made in changeset 303 and you can review and commit them as necessary.

Comment: This is perfect. I can keep current working changes and alter specific changesets and recommit selectively. Handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you know certain revision you want to revert here is one more way to revert it.

```
svn diff -c r1031 | grep ^Index | awk '{ print $2}' | xargs -I {file} svn export -r 1030 {file} {file}
```

It finds all files changed in r1031 and replace it with the same files from revision 1030.

P.S.: Also please, be careful if files you want to revert doesn't present in 1030. It could probably work not the way you expected.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog entry for details:

http://blog.mafr.de/2008/05/13/revert-a-commit-in-svn/

with some good background explanation:

> To understand what’s happening here requires some background on what
>   the merge command does conceptually: It records which changes have to
>   be made to revision N to turn it into revision N+1 (called a delta)
>   and applies it to the working copy. That’s not what we want in our
>   scenario, so we reverse the usual order of revisions on the command
>   line. Effectively, we tell the merge command to create a delta the
>   other way round. The result is a "rewinding" of the code base.

And also, in the comments, how to do this in TortoiseSVN:

> To do this with TortoiseSVN, you right-click the directory or file
>   you’d like to revert and use “Merge” from the TortoiseSVN menu. Select
>   the option “Merge two different trees”. Under “From” select the Head
>   revision. Under “To” select the old revision + 1 (i.e. if you’d like
>   to revert to revision 169, type revision 170 into the box).